# Creating self referencing ine to many relation in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I'm creating a table named **finishProducts** that has the following columns:

- product_id
- product_name
- product_unit
- product_components_count

Each finish product may be composed of more than one components, these components should also be one of the finish products.
So it is like one to many relationship where one finish product may or may not have more than one components (Finish Products).

What is the best practice to create a table for such scenario?

One of the solution that i think is to add multiple rows for same finish product with different product components. See attached Image.

[image: Solution 1]

But this solution might not be the best one because in future i might have to add another column named Color for this table where i would have to apply the same one to many rule (one product can have multiple colors).

So i'm searching for a best possible solution.

Comment: Does it have to be in one table? Personally I'd create different tables: `colors`, `products`, `units`, `product_relations` and relate them.

Comment: Yeah they are different tables. I'm confused about the composition because the components should also be from finish products.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have two tables, one for products and one for components. Then have a one to many relation ship to the components.

```
product_id | product_name 
--
12 | Epoxytile


Component_id | product_id | Component_name
--
1 | 12 | Expoxytile base
2 | 12 | Epoxytile grout
3 | 12 | Expsytile Silica
```

You can have however many components you need then. To query for them, just use

```
SELECT product_id, p.prouduct_name, c.compoent_name
FROM product p
     INNER JOIN compoent c ON p.product_id = c.product_id
```

Comment: will this not make my processing slow after adding the Color field also.

Comment: It'll be faster by not having so much duplicated data.

Comment: what about a lot of records lets say thousands of products with a lot of colors each

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your trying to get. Would the products have different colors or the individual components?

Comment: each product is available in more than 10 different colors.

Comment: exactly but with color names. Is this the proper way?? I mean with thousand of products, i'm just worried about the performance.